# Xaml - send viewmodel property to method in another viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a datagrid bound to a collection of ViewModels that have a property called Distance.  Is there a way in xaml to send that Distance property to a method in the ViewModel that the datagrid itemsource is on?
For example: (GetDistanceInKM would be on the same VM as the collection of reports)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReportViewModels}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColum Binding="{Binding Distance}" Header="Distance" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DistanceStyle}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Style x:Key="DistanceStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding={Binding GetDistanceInKM[Distance], Converter={StaticResource IsDistanceGreaterThanTen}} Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value={StaticResource HighlightBorderBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I think you need two-way binding here.  This tells your code to update the other value(s) everytime any one of them is changed so all the values are always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind to methods, only to properties. If you want to call a method when a property changes, do it in the setter of that property.
If i understood correctly you have two options:

1. When `Distance` is set, call `GetDistanceInKM` and modify a new property `DistanceInKM`. Then bind your `DataTrigger` to `DistanceInKM` using the converter as is now.
2. Bind your `DataTrigger` directly to `Distance` property and make the conversion to kms in a `IsDistanceGreaterThanTenKMs` Converter.